# R: dropping all observations within a group

Tags: r, conditional-statements, subset

I have a set of 500 firms with investment data over six years. I want to create a balanced panel of ONLY the firms that have data for all six years, but I can't seem to find an easy way to do this in R.

My data looks like:

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKlnz.png)

I want to drop a firm for all years if it has missing values for just one year. I've tried different conditional subsetting commands but nothing is working for me. Ideas?

Comment: If a firm can only have a max of 6 years of actual data, you could filter out any 'output' values that are NA/NULL, group by firm, summarise to get a count of records, and then you would receive a list of how many records per firm.  The only ones you want to keep are the ones that = 6 (i.e. 6 years of data).  If you filter that list for those firms, then you have the list to filter the original dataset with.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three methods:

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  firm = c(1, 1, 1, 2,  2,  2),
  year = c(1, 2, 3, 1,  2,  3),
  val  = c(1, 1, 1, 2, NA, NA)
)
```

## Base R

```r
do.call(
  rbind.data.frame,
  by(dat, dat$firm, function(x) if (!any(is.na(x$val))) x)
)
#     year firm val
# 1.1    1    1   1
# 1.2    2    1   1
# 1.3    3    1   1
```

or

```r
datrm <- dat[!complete.cases(dat),]
dat[ !dat$firm %in% datrm$firm, ]
```

## `data.table`

```r
library(data.table)
datDT <- as.data.table(dat)
datDT[, .SD[!any(is.na(val)),], by = "firm" ]
```

## `dplyr`

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(firm) %>%
  filter(!any(is.na(val))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: The data.table setup worked perfectly! Thank you so much!